# Browse and Select file for use in FileTransfer() in PhoneGap mobile app

Tags: android, cordova

How can we browse the phone memory and SD card for files and then select one to be used by the `FileTransfer()` function in `PhoneGap`.

I found out examples to load and send images, but nothing that would help me in selecting other type of files.

I'm sending the files to a PHP file.

Comment: Hi have u find any solution for this prblm?if so can u please share me i have same prblm but not able to get any solution. Can u please help me?

Answer (score 3):

You can browse and select a file using

```
this.photoDestinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
var source =  navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY;
navigator.camera.getPicture(successFn, errorFn, { quality: 50,
        destinationType: this.photoDestinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: source,
        mediaType: navigator.camera.MediaType.ALLMEDIA  });
```

This opens up the options where you can navigate and choose a file
on choosing it gives you a callback where you can receive the file path and then later pass it to FileTransfer(). hope that helps.

Comment: But this will give files from image gallery not from Sd card

Comment: Depends on the user's apps. For instance if you have GoogleDrive installed on the phone you will be able to choose a file from there as well.